# Incorrect data shown in calendar and incorrect today

Tags: calendar, bugs, date-and-time, cyanogenmod

Recently, my Google Agenda started show completely wrong data :

- In planning view, "Today" (9th) is showing in front of yesterday (8th), "yesterday" in front of the 7th which is 2 days from today, and "Tomorrow" in front of today (9th) !
- Every event is showing one day before, but the date shown under the title of the event is correct. I means that all events planned the tomorrow the 10th are displayed the 9th, which is still marked "tomorrow" but is today !  If I open the event, the date is correct. This is completely nonsense.
- Everything displays correctly in month and week views. Today is april 9th.
- Everything is OK on my other phone, and on the web version.

Here are some screenshots (taken on april 9th, 06:22 PM, UTC+1) :

[image: Planning View]

[image: Week View]

[image: Month View]

What I already tried :

- Remove Google account calendar sync, setting back, forcing calendar sync
- Rebooting my phone
- Uninstalling Google Agenda app, and reinstalling
- Using another calendar apps (they all acted the same !)
- Emptying cache
- Emptying Dalvik cache

I only found one guy with the same problem : 
[Here](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z-Ultra/Calendar-Bug-on-Kitkat-4-4-2/td-p/612541)

My device : Samsung Galaxy Nexus, with CyanogenMod 11 M2, Android 4.4.2

Any idea what I'm missing here ?